# How to fix the error "argument "modelName" is missing, with no default" when using MVN package

Tags: r, maven, multivariate-testing, iris-dataset

I am using the `MVN` package, in R, to find whether each class of the dataset `iris` is multivariate normal or not.
I used the below code earlier in the day and generated results from it. However, I went to revisit it and now keep getting the following error message:

```r
Error in mvn(data = iris[Species == m[1], 1:4], mvnTest = c("mardia")) : 
  argument "modelName" is missing, with no default
```

Can not figure out what this means and how to fix it !

Code:

```
#Mardia's Test
SM<-mvn(data=iris,subset="Species", mvnTest="mardia")

SM$multivariateNormality

SetosaPlot<-mvn(data=iris, subset="Species", multivariatePlot="qq")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You loaded the `mclust` package.  When you did so you should have seen a warning

> The following object is masked from ‘package:MVN’: mvn

So now `mvn()` is calling `mclust::mvn()` (i.e. the `mvn` function in the `mclust` package) rather than `MVN::mvn()`.

- In general you can make sure you get the version from the `MVN` package by using

```
MVN::mvn(data=iris, subset="Species", multivariatePlot="qq")
```

- If you want to know where R is finding `mvn`, try `find("mvn")`
- In general, to resolve these kinds of problems you should start a clean R session, so that you know you're starting with no packages loaded.

(By the way, no real data set is **ever** truly multivariate normal; you're not testing "whether it is MVN or not", but rather whether it is *close enough to MVN that you can't reject the null hypothesis of multivariate normality ...*)